# How can I parse variables from JSON to Python?

Tags: python, json

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate post. I have read through the numerous others regarding this kind of issue, but have had no success.

I want to parse the below JSON to Python, to print the current price of the stock.
I have tried this using the below code:

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json

stock = json.loads(getQuotes('AAPL'))
print(stock['LastTradePrice'])
```

However, this gives the below error...

[image: error]

I have tried also the below code:

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json

print(json.dumps(getQuotes('AAPL'), indent=2))
```

Which successfully gives the following output

```
[
  {
    "Index": "NASDAQ",
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "129.09",
    "LastTradeDateTime": "2015-03-02T16:04:29Z",
    "LastTradePrice": "129.09",
    "Yield": "1.46",
    "LastTradeTime": "4:04PM EST",
    "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "Mar 2, 4:04PM EST",
    "Dividend": "0.47",
    "StockSymbol": "AAPL",
    "ID": "22144"
  }
]
```

However, I just want to fetch the price from this and parse it through to a Python program. Why am I unable to do this? I have a feeling that it is because of the square brackets surrounding the json, but am unsure.

Comment: What about `print(stock[0]['LastTradePrice'])`? It is a list after all, with one element.

Comment: Apparently, `qetQuotes` deals with the `json` deserializing already, and is returning a Python object. Why would you `dumps` it?

Comment: How would I fetch it as a python object? Treat it like an accociative array?

Comment: It *already returns a Python object*. It is a list of dicts.

Comment: stock = getQuotes('AAPL'); print(stock[0]['LastTradePrice']) # 119.97

Comment: Is dicts short for something?

Comment: A `dict` is the name Python uses for an associative array. AKA hashmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to deserialize the data since it returns an list of dictionaries.

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
data = getQuotes('AAPL')

print(data[0]['LastTradePrice'])
```

**Output:**

```
119.97
```

Comment: A *list*. It returns a *list*.